# multiple ajax forms in the same mvc 4 view doesn't work properly - after the second time of submit my model is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a class Cart with property Lines which returns me a collection of type CartLine.  here is my two classes Cart ad CartLine

```
public class Cart
    {

    private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();
    public String Currency { get; set; }

    public void UpdateCart(int ArticleID, string selectedQuantityType, int Quantity)
    {
        CartLine line = lineCollection.Where(p => p.Product.ArticleID == ArticleID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (line != null)
        {
            line.SelectedQuantityType = selectedQuantityType;
            line.Quantity = Quantity;

        }        
    }     


    public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
    {
        get { return lineCollection; }
    }
}
```

<
And here  is my class  CartLine

```
 public class CartLine
        {
            public CartLine()
            { 
                this.QuantityType= new List<QuantityType>();

            }
            public WebServiceBeaMenu Product { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public string Currency { get; set; } 
            public string SelectedQuantityType { get; set; }

        }
```

I've got two actions which returns me strongly typed PartialView  - CartIndexViewModel with two properties - one from Type `Cart`

```
          public ActionResult CartPartial(string returnUrl)
            {

                return PartialView(new CartIndexViewModel
                {

                    Cart = GetCart(),
                    ReturnUrl = returnUrl
                });
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult CartPartial(CartLine line)
            {
                Cart crt = GetCart();
                crt.UpdateCart(line.Product.ArticleID, line.SelectedQuantityType, line.Quantity);            

                return PartialView(new CartIndexViewModel
                {
                    Cart = crt
                });           
            }    



 private Cart GetCart() 
        {
            Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
            if (cart == null) 
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }
```

ANd here is my view whih loop through all thre cartlines of my cart and display their quantity and quantityType.
The problem is as you see  for each `CartLine` I'm making an ajax form so when there is a change in the quantity of a CartLine (when there is a change in this helper  @`Html.TextBoxFor(x => line.Quantity,new { id = @liine.Product.ArticleID, onchange="SubmitForm(this.id)" })`) you see that I submit the form to the httppost form of my `CartPartial` Action. The first time when I submit the form there is no problem and thanks to mvc model binding my `CartLine` parameter is filled with the data I need. The problem is when this action returns me the same view with the updated data  after that if  I try to change a quantity and  submit the form for the second time my `CartLine` parameter  is empty. What may be the reason. Thankls in advance.

```
@model MvcBeaWeb.Models.CartIndexViewModel


<div id="cartContainer">

       <table width="100%"  align="center" style="margin:auto;border-collapse:collapse;">

          <tbody>

            @foreach(var line in Model.Cart.Lines) 
            {

             <tr style="height:90px" > 


              @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CartPartial", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "centerCartBody", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { id = "form" + @line.Product.ArticleID }))
              {


                <td align="left">@line.Product.SpecialWord</td>
                <td >                   
                  <div class="inner-content">

                       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => line.Quantity,new { id = @liine.Product.ArticleID, onchange="SubmitForm(this.id)" })
                       <span  class="qty-type">
                       @Html.DropDownListFor(x => line.SelectedQuantityType, new SelectList(line.QuantityType, "QuantityID", "Description"))
                       </span>

                   </div>

                </td>

                 @Html.HiddenFor(x => line.Product.ArticleID, "Value");   

              }
                </tr>


              }   

        </tbody>
     </table>  

               <div >
                   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index/","Confirmation"))
                   {
                       <input type="submit" id="btnCheckOut"  />

                   }
               </div>               
       </div>     

   </div>

 </div>
script>
function SubmitForm(id)
 {
     $("#form_" + id).submit();

 }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you console_log(id); in your SubmitForm? Is the value correct when you submit for the second time?

Comment: I alerted the id of the form - everything is OK!  This problem is driving me crazy!!

Comment: Are you sure that id corresponds to the expected id at the server-side?